# Como pegar variável e imprimir vários "<li>" de acordo com o numero da variável?

Tags: php, for

Tenho uma variável `$abas = 4`.

Preciso que o PHP faça um `echo` no número da variável, nesse caso seriam 4 echos.

O resultado deveria ser:

```
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
```

Sou iniciante em PHP, qual a melhor forma de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para o que você está querendo fazer, recomendo utilizar o `for`.

Exemplo:

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $abas; $i++): ?>
    <li><?= $i ?></li>
<?php endfor ?>
```

O `for` é uma Estrutura de Repetição, que, como o nome sugere, tem como finalidade executar uma quantidade de repetições enquanto a condição do segundo parâmetro é atendida.

Ele é dividido em três partes:

- o início. No caso `$i = 1` é o valor de definição inicial.
- a condição para a repetição continuar executando. No caso, enquanto `$i` for menor ou igual a `$abas`.
- O que fazer após realizar uma incrementação. Nesse caso, `$i++` incrementa `+1` em `$i` para o próximo loop.

O trecho `<?= $i ?>` encarregará de imprimir o valor atual de `$i` no HTML.

Nas versões anteriores a 5.4 do PHP, você teria que usar `<?php echo $i; ?>`.

Comment: show, isso mesmo